# SQL Server 2012 Query - Second highest among a group of records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a "Principal" table which can have multiple EmployeeId's. For each employee id, there is an ownership percent.  This table also maintains principal name for each ownership percent. For e.g

```
EmpId                OwnershipPercent              Name
-------              -----------------             ---------
100                      50                           John
100                      30                           Neil
100                      20                           Mark
```

Now, I need to fetch the highest and second highest ownership % with its name,  for each employee. For that I used the following query to get ownership %: -

```
SELECT
    EmpId, CAST(isNULL([First], 0) AS DECIMAL (12,2)) [First OwnershipPercent], 
    CAST(isNULL([Second],0) AS DECIMAL (12,2)) [Second OwnershipPercent]
FROM 
(
    SELECT EmpId, OwnershipPercent, CASE WHEN SNo = 1 THEN 'First' ELSE 'Second' END [Priority]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by MerchantId order by MerchantId, OwnershipPercent desc) [SNo], * 
        FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT EmpId, OwnershipPercent FROM Principal) t
    ) t1
    WHERE t1.SNo <=2
) t2
PIVOT
(
Avg(OwnershipPercent) FOR Priority IN ([First],[Second])
)AS pvt
```

I am unable to get the names with each% with this query. Please help

Comment: Well you forgot to tell us how do you want output to look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a `GROUP BY` and use `CASE WHEN`. Something like this.

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT EmpId, Name,OwnershipPercent,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY EmpId ORDER BY OwnershipPercent DESC) rn
FROM Principal
)
SELECT EmpID,
MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Name END) Highest,
MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN OwnershipPercent END) Highest_perc,
MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN Name END) SecondHighest,
MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN OwnershipPercent END) SecondHighest_perc
FROM CTE
WHERE rn IN (1,2)
GROUP BY EmpID
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2012 supports additional Windowed Aggregate Function, in this case you need LEAD:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
       MerchantId, 
       OwnershipPercent,      -- current row
       LEAD(OwnershipPercent) -- next row
       over(partition by MerchantId 
            order by OwnershipPercent desc) AS nextPercent,
       LEAD(Name) -- next row
       over(partition by MerchantId 
            order by OwnershipPercent desc) AS nextName,
       ROW_NUMBER(OwnershipPercent)
       over(partition by MerchantId 
            order by OwnershipPercent desc) AS SNo
    FROM Principal
    -- GROUP BY works the same as DISTINCT
    GROUP BY MerchantId, OwnershipPercent
 ) t
WHERE SNo = 1
```

Comment: both the options worked fine.

dnoeth - thanks for this. Could you please suggest how to find the other required values like Name in your query